# RegularExpression for the textbox which allows only certain symbols

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a text box.In my text box I should enter the age Range as numbers.

In my text box the age range should allow only any one of the symbol as
    `-,>=,<=,>,<` or `only number.`

```
Examples are 30-40,>30,>=30,<30,<=30,30
```

only these symbols are allowed.
    I have to validate this textbox,please give the regular expression for this textbox.

Comment: did any of our answers help you?

Answer (score 1):

You will not need javascript for this, html5 form elements can be validated with the pattern attribute. Here's an example tag:

```
<input type="text" name="agerange" pattern="[\-<>=\d+]+">
```

Read [about html5 forms at html5rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/forms/html5forms/#toc-validation).

This first regular expression just checks for valid characters:

```
^[\-<>=\d+]+$
```

You can test it out [here](https://www.debuggex.com/r/DbYkIs5U6eRh5aSt/2), they give a nice diagram there.
To break the regex down:

```
^     means: at the start of the string
[ ]   the square brackets give a list of characters we want to match
[ ]+  the plus at the end of the square brackets are a loop, meaning "one or more of these"
$     means: at the end of the string
\-    the minus sign needs a backslash to escape it
<     just stands for itself
>     just stands for itself
=     just stands for itself
\d    matches any digit
```

so to summarize it in english: this regular expression will match any string
that contains minus, less-than, greater-than, equal-signs and/or digits in any order. and the string may contain nothing else.

To also get the syntax right use

```
^(?:\d+-|>=?|<=?|=)?\d+$
```

test it online [here](https://www.debuggex.com/r/DbYkIs5U6eRh5aSt/4)

This is a bit more tricky to explain, the diagram from debggex should really help:

[image: diagam for regular experession]

To start with the smalles parts:

```
X+     a plus sign after something means "one or more of these", so
\d+-   means one or more numbers followed by a minus sign
X?     a question mark after something means "zero or one of these", so
=?     means either an equal sign or nothing at all, so 
>=?    means a greater-than sign followed by an optional equal-sign
>=?    means a greater-than sign followed by an optional equal-sign
```

if you zoom out a bit you can see that the fragments we just discussed are separated
by pipe-signs:

```
\d+-|>=?|<=?|=     so this is either digigs followed by a minus,
                                  or  greater-than, possibly followed by an equal sign
                                  or  less-than, possibly followed by an equal sign
                                  or  just an equal sign
```

These four alternatives are encolsed in a special sort of bracket:

```
(?:X)        means: group this together, but do not save the results
```

we could also use

```
(X)          which will wave the matched string into a special variable.
```

This should give you all the bits and pieces to  understand the whole pattern.

Comment: I dont know html5,How sholu i use it.

Comment: @reddy You should use an up to date Web Browser. and set doctype to `<!DOCTYPE html>` you can learn it here [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/html/) or in [codecademy](http://www.codecademy.com)

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
/^((\d+)|(\d+\-\d+)|((>|(>=)|<|(<=))\d+))$/
```

bjelli: your pattern would match `3>30`

Comment: this does not actually match plain numbers like "30", see https://www.debuggex.com/r/wVot214kNYIwccpL/1

Comment: works perfectly, see it in action at https://www.debuggex.com/r/wVot214kNYIwccpL/2